# Django models - foreign key object date rewriting

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, models, django-queryset

I have such situation:

Models:

```
class Test2(models.Model) {
  date = models.DateField(editable=False)
}

class Test(models.Model) {
  test2 = models.ForeignKey(Test2)
}
```

Action:

```
for test_obj in Test.objects.all():
  test2_obj = test_obj.test2
  test2_obj.date = date.today()
  test2_obj.save()
  test_obj.save()
```

After that action, date of `test2_obj` is not changed. Why? Is `test2_obj = test_obj.test2` a copy?

Comment: Can you show the test code that makes you believe that it's not changed?

Comment: SELECT * FROM app_test2; :)

Comment: remove the line `test_obj.save()`

Comment: In real situation i need that line. It makes a problem? Maybe should i move it before first save?

Answer (score 0):

i create testapp and test you problem

> models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Test2(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(editable=False)

class Test(models.Model):
    test2 = models.ForeignKey(Test2)
```

> tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from models import Test, Test2

from datetime import datetime, date

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_field_update(self):
        old_date = date(2012,11,11)
        current_date = datetime.today().date()

        t2 = Test2(date = old_date)
        t2.save()

        t1 = Test(test2 = t2)
        t1.save()


        for test_obj in Test.objects.all():
            test2_obj = test_obj.test2
            test2_obj.date = current_date
            test2_obj.save()
            test_obj.save()

        t2 = Test2.objects.all()[0]

        self.assertEqual(t2.date, current_date)
```

run tests

.. >manage.py test testapp

Creating test database for alias 'default'... .
---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 0.016s

OK Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

so you this is work as expected, not as you posted.

Comment: I dont want an answer how to do it because i know it. I want to know why its like this.

Comment: show you full code, as i wrote in my answer it should work as expected, not as you posted